# Descobrir o formato de arquivos sem extensão

Tags: java

Tenho milhares de fotos em meu computador porém sem a extensão.

Como a extensão foi excluída, gostaria de alguma biblioteca Java para manipular esses arquivos/fotos que estão sem extensão e então descobrir seu formato para poder renomear. Como são milhares de fotos, ficar verificando uma por uma levará muito tempo. E como gosto de Java, será um aprendizado a mais também.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode chamar o [Trid](http://mark0.net/soft-trid-e.html) através de um comando do sistema por dentro do Java. Ele já tem até a opção de já renomear pra você os arquivos adicionando a extensão.

Note que o Trid tem um executável pra cada sistema operacional, então você vai ter que ter uma lógica pra cada sistema ao qual for dar suporte.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode fazer a sim pegar o arquivo sem extensão e converter para um com a extensão desejada.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        String path = "C:\\Files\\Foto";

        byte[] imageInByte;
        BufferedImage originalImage = ImageIO.read(new File(
                path));


        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        String contentType = new Tika().detect(baos.toByteArray());
        ImageIO.write(originalImage, contentType, baos);
        baos.flush();
        imageInByte = baos.toByteArray();
        baos.close();


        InputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(imageInByte);
        BufferedImage bImageFromConvert = ImageIO.read(in);

        ImageIO.write(bImageFromConvert, contentType, new File(
                "C:\\Files\\Foto));

    }
```

Usa essa **lib** para detectar o tipo de arquivo: https://www.apache.org/dyn/closer.cgi, baixa e coloca no seu classpath.

Comment: Digamos que o nome do meu arquivo esteja em "C:\Files\Foto", onde foto está sem sua extensão então ele gera uma exception dizendo que o arquivo não existe.

Comment: Qual exception ?

Comment: TESTEI AQUI FICOU BOM!!